# Do we have a way to include full source into APK?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I'm developing samples for different Android technologies and want to include the full source code (Eclipse project) archived into the APK. That should allow anyone with Google Market access to easily reuse the code.

Is there a proper way to automatically pack the code/resources and put it into assets? 
I'm using Eclipse under Win//Linux.

Currently I have to manually 7z-compress the src&res and put it into assets before signing.

Comment: Why not https://github.com/ or http://code.google.com/ ?

Comment: The idea is to have an APK only. The user may install it, check if the result is OK with him and unpack the source if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just compress it and include it in a directory under your APK (e.g. raw). But be aware that your APK will at least x2 its size.

Comment: Seems like I badly explained the problem. The nice-to-have here is to have it automatically packed. If I make changes in src&res I have to manually copy all the files into 'raw' before building. Should I add a custom build command? I'll try...

Comment: You can pack as JAR, this is easily done through Eclipse (Export -> Java -> JAR)

Comment: I think it's time to add a custom builder step. Make a batch/bast script and just call it from.